# Entering Safe Mode problem

Tags: windows-xp, safe-mode

When i start my pc i get following message:

```
The Logon User Interface DLL RtlGina2.dll failed to load
```

I found solution [here](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.security.homeusers&tid=0ea79537-f61f-4688-8629-b2d009f1b734&p=1)

But i ca not log into my pc, neither in safe/normal mode. It is interesting that first time
i succeed loging into safe mode, but change msconfig boot.ini to safemode with networking where i can not log in. And now every time no matter what i am choosing from F8 menu, i enter in safe mode with networking(where i get following error). So is it any way to log in back into "pure" safe mode. I am not sure that the question it`s clear enough ;-(

Answer (score 0):

If u have ur windows XP installation disk

1. Boot into disk
2. Run repair install

> XP Repair install
>
> Please read carefully and make sure
>   you followed the warning links before
>   initiating the Repair Install. You can
>   print a text version for reference.
>   repair.txt
>
> Boot the computer using the XP CD. You
>   may need to change the boot order in
>   the system BIOS so the CD boots before
>   the hard drive. Check your system
>   documentation for steps to access the
>   BIOS and change the boot order. When
>   you see the "Welcome To Setup" screen,
>   you will see the options below   This
>   portion of the Setup program prepares
>   Microsoft     Windows XP to run on
>   your computer:
>
> To setup Windows XP now, press
>   ENTER.
>
> To repair a Windows XP installation
>   using Recovery Console, press R.
>
> To quit Setup without installing
>   Windows XP, press F3.
>
> Press Enter to start the Windows
>   Setup.   Do Not choose "To repair a
>   Windows XP installation using the
>   Recovery Console, press  R", (you Do
>   Not want to load Recovery Console). I
>   repeat, Do Not choose "To repair a
>   Windows XP installation using the
>   Recovery Console, press  R".  Accept
>   the License Agreement and Windows will
>   search for existing Windows
>   installations. Select the XP
>   installation you want to repair from
>   the list and press R to start the
>   repair. If Repair is not one of the
>   options, END setup. After the reboot
>   read  Warning#2! Setup will copy the
>   necessary files to the hard drive and
>   reboot.  Do not press any key to boot
>   from CD when the message appears.
>   Setup will continue as if it were
>   doing a clean install, but your
>   applications and settings will remain
>   intact.

http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm

Comment: Thanks for helping, i repaired windows xp via your steps, after this windows reboot... i`m choosing againg boot from CD to continue my installation? And againt window with there options appears...
To setup Windows XP now, press ENTER.

To repair a Windows XP installation using Recovery Console, press R.

To quit Setup without installing Windows XP, press F3.
?

Comment: Do not let it boot from the CD the second time, the repair will continue.